Unlocked Package Generation fails due to dependency on Manage Package
I have created and released a Managed package "A".
I am now trying to create a small extension (which includes some Reports and Dashboards) as an Unlocked Package.
The reports contains Summary formulas which are dependent on fields introduced as part of the Managed Package.
Therefore, I mention the Manage package as a dependency in the sfdx-project.json
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true,
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "package": "MP_A",
          "versionNumber": "1.10.0.LATEST"
        }
      ],
      "package": "Unlocked Package B",
      "versionName": "ver 0.1",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "versionDescription": ""
    }
  ],
  "name": "Unlocked Package B",
  "namespace": "MP_namespace",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "59.0",
  "packageAliases": {
    "MP_A" : "0HoXXXXXXXXX",
    "Unlocked Package B": "0HoXXXXXXXX"
  }
}

However, when I run the package version create command
sf package version create --package "Unlocked Package B" --installation-key test1234 --wait 10

the command fails and complains about a report that has a summary formula. That summary formula refers to the field introduced by the Manage Package.
(1) Value_Selling_Opportunity_Coverage_Repor_Ypy: customAggregates: 
Invalid custom summary formula definition: Field Opportunity.MP_namespace__Has_Discoveries__c:SUM does not exist. Check spelling.

I will appreciate any help and pointers on how to resolve this. My understanding was that the "package version create" command  will create a scratch org and install the dependent Manage package and therefore this issue should not arise.

Where is the 04t managed package version alias?

Hi @PhilW i was able to get it to work. The issue was the unlocked package metadata was referring to fields from the dependent package with its namespace included (MP_namespace__Has_Discoveries__c). The unlocked package also had the same namespace. Removing the MP_namespace from the report and dashboard metadata resolved the issue.

Please take a minute to turn your comment into a self answer then select your answer as "best". That way this question is closed off cleanly for later searches.

Thanks for the advise @PhilW. I have done as you suggested.

I was able to resolve the issue.
The unlocked package metadata was referring to fields from the dependent package with its namespace included (MP_namespace__Has_Discoveries__c).
The unlocked package also had the same namespace.
Removing the MP_namespace from the report and dashboard metadata resolved the issue.
